# Full Screen mode detection in 150% zoom is not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working in react where I have to detect if the web app is in full screen mode or not.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setfullScreen(window.innerHeight === window.screen.height)
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);
```

Above piece of code works well in normal(100%) zoom and detect if the web app is in full screen mode or not.

But when zoomed to 150% it won't detect the full screen mode.

Is there a better way to detect full screen mode in react which works for all zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
const zoom = window.devicePixelRatio;

setFullscreen(
  window.screen.height === Math.round(window.innerHeight * zoom)
);
```